# Retrofit Response Json

Tags: java, android, json, rest, retrofit

I'm developing an app for Android, and REST Server returns the following JSON answer when I submit a `GET`:

```
{
    "result": "ok",
    "code": 1000,
    "code_desc": "Command Done Successfully",
    "method": "get",
    "call_id": null,
    "timestamp": 1539100644,
    "weight": {
        "1": {
            "id": 1,
            "customer_id": 1,
            "date": "2018-10-04 12:02:00",
            "value": 100,
            "observations": ""
        },
        "2": {
            "id": 2,
            "customer_id": 1,
            "date": "2018-10-04 12:02:00",
            "value": 100,
            "observations": ""
        }
    },
    "order": "date",
    "sorder": "ASC",
    "total": 2
}
```

JSON is valid, but when I'm trying to read the contents, it returns `null`.
I think that it is because the object Weight has bad formation.

Should the JSON from server be changed? to something like:

```
{
                "result": "ok",
                "code": 1000,
                "code_desc": "Command Done Successfully",
                "method": "get",
                "call_id": null,
                "timestamp": 1539100644,
                "weight": [{
                                               "id": 1,
                                               "customer_id": 1,
                                               "date": "2018-10-04 12:02:00",
                                               "value": 100,
                                               "observations": ""
                               },
                               {
                                               "id": 2,
                                               "customer_id": 1,
                                               "date": "2018-10-04 12:02:00",
                                               "value": 100,
                                               "observations": ""
                               }
                ],
                "order": "date",
                "sorder": "ASC",
                "total": 2
}
```

Comment: Perhaps posting the code you use to parse the JSON will give some insight.

Comment: Can you post your Get Retrofit method? url can be dummy but please put your parameter, please.

Comment: @Headers("Accept: application/json")
    @GET("/api/social/medical_clinic/1/weight")
    public Call <PostWeight> getAllWeights();

Answer (score -1):

Most likely you are trying to read a response into some `List<Object>` whereas a Server response looks like a `Map<String, Object>`. Try to change your code taking it into account

Comment: What can I do if there 33000 thousand records?
I simply should not create an weight object for each one.

Comment: Why downvote? I'ne just wanned to say taht the "weight": {
        "1": {
            ***
        },
        "2": {
            ***
        } will deserialize into Map<String,Object>  and that is true.
And "weight": [*** ] will deserialize into List<Object> and is also true. So why downvote?